# Looping in ibatis mapper xml

Tags: java, ibatis

```
<insert id="saveRecommendedProductSkus">
        INSERT INTO PIM_SKU_RECOMMENDED_SKU VALUES (#{skuId},
        <foreach collection="skuIdArr" item="aaskuId">
            #{aaskuId}
        </foreach>
        ,#{productRecommendationType});
    </insert>
```

I am sending a list called `skuIdArr` from java class. Here in the ibatis xml I want to iterate through that list.

Comment: I don't see the XML file

Comment: Why do you need to see the xml. I just want to loop in this select id through skuIdArr list which i am sending from java.